# React.Suspense expected string after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A recent update caused my React.Suspense fallback to throw this error:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

This exact code used to work and I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on which package to roll back(?)

// App.jsx

```
<Suspense fallback={<Fallback/>}>...</Suspense>
```

Here's my Fallback component:

```
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';
import React from 'react';

export const MediaUploading = ({
  t = 'Grid',
  c = '#121d66',
  h = '60',
  w = '60',
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="media-uploading">
      <Loader type={t} color={c} height={h} width={w} timeout={0} />
    </div>
  );
};

// fallback
export const Fallback = ({
  t = 'Grid',
  c = '#121d66',
  h = '100',
  w = '100',
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="loading">
      <Loader type={t} color={c} height={h} width={w} timeout={0} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you share the coder where you use the Fallback component with us? Also any imports of Fallback if there are any.

Comment: "recent update" specifics & what does your current `package.json` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when `react-loader-spinner` moved to v5, they dropped their `Loader` component and removed the default export. So if you want to keep using the `Loader`, then stick to `react-spinner-loader@4`.

v4 - only has a default export (no named exports)

`import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";`

v5 - only has named exports (no default export)

`import { Grid } from "react-loader-spinner";`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I actually eventually figured this out. I had done a `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest` and didn't pay enough attention to breaking changes :) Haste.